# Select multiple values in a column identified by an unique ID and parse them into a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the following Table "MyTable":

```
 ID          StrValue            SortID 
 130030      12345678            2 
 130030      Huber               3 
 130030      Georg Hans          5 
 130801      11223344            2 
 130801      Schreiner           3 
 130801      Peter               5 
 131244      87654321            2 
 131244      Schneider           3 
 131244      Hans                5
```

I want to write an SQL to get the Data into this format/select:

```
Result
12345678, Huber Georg Hans
11223344, Schreiner Peter
87654321, SChneider Hans
```

Does this makes sense and if yes which functions should be used to get the above mentioned result table? If you have the solution please provide it to us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try using case when expression

```
SELECT id,
   max(case when sortid=2 then StrValue end),
   max(case when sortid=3 then StrValue end),
   max(case when sortid=5 then StrValue end)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Omg! Cool that was to easy :D Thanks a lot!!! I have just gave the aggregate functions an alias and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

CSV string using for xml method

```
 select Result = stuff( 
        (
            select  ',' + x.StrValue
            from    YourTable x
            where   x.ID    = t.ID
            order by x.SortID
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
from    YourTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE(ID,StrValue,SortID )
AS
(
SELECT 130030,'12345678'  ,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 130030,'Huber'     ,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 130030,'Georg Hans',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 130801,'11223344'  ,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 130801,'Schreiner' ,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 130801,'Peter'     ,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 131244,'87654321'  ,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 131244,'Schneider' ,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 131244,'Hans'      ,5 
)
,Cte2
AS
(
SELECT ID,StrValue,
        CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(StrValue) >0 
        THEN StrValue ELSE NULL END AS INT) AS StrValueNumeric ,
        SortID
FROM CTE
)
,CTE_Final
AS
(
 SELECT ID,SortID,StrValue,
        CASE WHEN StrValueNumeric IS NOT NULL THEN StrValueNumeric
 ELSE (SELECT  MAX(StrValueNumeric) 
        FROM Cte2
        WHERE StrValueNumeric IS NOT NULL 
            AND id = o.id 
        )END AS StrValueNumeric
FROM Cte2 o
)
SELECT DISTINCT
LTRIM(STUFf((SELECT ',  ' + StrValue 
                    FROM CTE_Final i 
                    WHERE i.StrValueNumeric = o.StrValueNumeric
                    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')) As StrValue
FROM CTE_Final o
```

Result

```
ReqFormat
-----------------------------
11223344,  Schreiner,  Peter
12345678,  Huber,  Georg Hans
87654321,  Schneider,  Hans
```